# Is it possible to import this multitone svg filter into a program and finetune the effect with the use of sliders?

Tags: css, user-interface, svg-filters

I would like to import this svg filter into an program and fine tune the filter with the use of sliders and live view, so I could achieve the exact look that I want.
Is there such a software that is suitable for this?

```
<svg class="levels_ui--svgContainer" width="320" height="280" viewBox="0 0 320 280" preserveaspectration="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs class="levels_ui--svgDefs"><filter id="multitone_filter_1"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.0392156862745098 0.1803921568627451 0.9450980392156862 0.4117647058823529 0.9647058823529412"></feFuncR><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.054901960784313725 0.38823529411764707 0.27058823529411763 0.7490196078431373 0.8901960784313725"></feFuncG><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.058823529411764705 0.30980392156862746 0.0196078431372549 0.6039215686274509 0.5803921568627451"></feFuncB></feComponentTransfer></filter></defs>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for this, I found an app for this:

http://filtered.sourceforge.net/

It's not with sliders as I wanted (I wanted to be able to adjust contrast and such with sliders), but it's a great program.